# Using Color specified in SpriteBatch.Draw with Custom shader

Tags: c#, xna, shader, spritebatch

Normally when you do `SpriteBatch.Draw` you can specify a color. But here's the problem. If I use custom shaders they ignore color passed by `SpriteBatch.Draw`...

How do I  take that into account? I mean how exactly `SpriteBatch.Draw` passes a color? If I know it I can use it in my shader.

So far what I have (relevant part):

```
float4 NoEffects(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    return tex2D(s0, coords);
}

technique Default
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 NoEffects();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to retrieve the color that's passed through the vertex shader and use it when calculating your final output:

```
float4 NoEffects(float4 color : COLOR0, float2 coords : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    return tex2D(s0, coords) * color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EffectParameter to pass a value to your effect.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976060.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I know that already, obivously... What I would like do, as I described in the question, is to use the color passed by SpriteBatch.Draw(); instead of passing it myself again.